# сниффер для андроида

Tags: android

Всем привет.

Есть задание по учёбе - написать любую программу для андроид ..

Появилась идея - по поводу написания сниффера сети..

Хотел узнать какими знаниями надо обладать для такой задачи ? Конечно кроме самого API андроида.

Comment: не уверен что это хорошая идея. Фактически вам надо читать о `vpn` клиентах. Если телефон рутован что есть старый добрый `tcpdump` но без рута вроде бы не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. TCP|IP Желательно хорошо знать;
2. Изучить саму технологию снифинга, их есть несколько видов;
3. Выбрать сферу, легальная(проверка сетей и тд.) "Анализатор сети", или не   легальная (Подслушивание,перехват паролей и тд.);
4. API и вообще разработку под android(Желательно иметь опыт);
5. Знать ЯП, который хорошо встанет на android без костылей;

Я конечно не мастер в сфере снифинга, но по моему имея такой багаж знаний. Уже сам найдешь все что требуется.

Comment: Tо есть написание сетигого снифера это достаточно серьезное дело ? Буду рад если дашь ссылку на книгу по снифингу сетей.

Comment: Ну сам подумай, ты хочешь перехватывать по сути трафик и сканировать его. Конечно дело не из простых. При том ты хочешь его портировать под android. Можешь поискать исходники таких сниферов как sleep droid, shark и тд. (На git может есть).
По поводу книги, я бы дал конечно. Но у меня нет подобной литературы в google я толком нечего не нашел. Поищи статьи может, на тему : Сканирования сетей, перехвата траффика, расшифровки\криптографии и тп.
Ты взял серьезную задачу, осуществить сложно. Но возможно.
Чем смог тем помог, прости что больше нечем не могу помочь. :D

Comment: Если интересно, можешь тут глянуть: 
[Вот тут глянь](http://www1.hut.ru/aneksniff/sniffer3.html)
  Может найдешь что - то .
**Удачи!**